# circle collision practice, advice?

Tags: java

can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong? i'm trying to get the circles to bounce off each other but they don't seem to be working.i keep making changes to fix the issue but that only makes more issues, whilst the main issue isn't resolved. have i used the wrong math's algorithm to check for collisions? or is it right and i have just made an error i cant seem to find? any help would be appreciated.

```
public float[][] CreateDots() {
    if (first == true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dotNumber; i++) {
            do{
            dotX = r.nextInt(300);
            dotY = r.nextInt(300);
            dotWidth = r.nextFloat() * 50;
            dotRadius = dotWidth / 2;
            dotMass = r.nextFloat() / 10;
            dotCentreX = dotX + dotRadius;
            dotCentreY = dotY + dotRadius;
            dotVelocityX = r.nextFloat();
            dotVelocityY = r.nextFloat();

            dots[i][0] = dotX;
            dots[i][1] = dotY;
            dots[i][2] = dotVelocityX;
            dots[i][3] = dotVelocityY;
            dots[i][4] = dotRadius;
            dots[i][5] = dotCentreX;
            dots[i][6] = dotCentreY;
            dots[i][7] = dotMass;
            dots[i][8] = dotWidth;


            }while(collision == true);
        }
        first = false;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < dotNumber; i++) {
            dots[i][0] = dots[i][0] + dots[i][2];
            dots[i][1] = dots[i][1] + dots[i][3];

            if (dots[i][0] + dots[i][8] >= wallX) {
                dots[i][2] = -dots[i][2];
            }
            if (dots[i][1] + dots[i][8] >= wallY) {
                dots[i][3] = -dots[i][3];
            }

            if (dots[i][0] < 0) {
                dots[i][2] = -dots[i][2];
            }
            if (dots[i][1] < 0) {
                dots[i][3] = -dots[i][3];
            }

        }
    }

    repaint();

    return dots;
}

public void bounce() {
    collisionDot = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < dotNumber; i++) {
        for (int a = i + 1; a < dotNumber; a++) {
            // difference between the x and y velocity of two dots
            float xVelDiff = dots[i][2] - dots[a][2];
            float yVelDiff = dots[i][3] - dots[a][3];
            //difference between the centre x and y of two dots
            float xDist = dots[i][5] - dots[a][5];
            float yDist = dots[i][6] - dots[a][6];
            System.out.println(xVelDiff + " * " + xDist + " + " + yVelDiff + " * " + yDist + " = "+ (xVelDiff * xDist + yVelDiff * yDist));
            //not quite sure yet
            if (xVelDiff * xDist + yVelDiff * yDist <= 0) {
                angleCollision = (float) -Math.atan2(dots[a][0] - dots[i][0], dots[a][1] - dots[i][1]);

                float mass = (dots[i][7] + dots[a][7]);
                float mass2 = (dots[i][7] - dots[a][7]);

                // x and y velocity and angle of collision for the two dots
                float[] u1 = rotate(dots[i][2], dots[i][3], (float) angleCollision);
                float[] u2 = rotate(dots[a][2], dots[a][3], (float) angleCollision);

                //Velocity of dot 1
                float[] v1 = new float[2];
                v1[0] = u1[0] * mass2 / mass + u2[0] * 2 * dots[a][7] / (mass);
                v1[1] = u1[1];

                // velocity of dot 2
                float[] v2 = new float[2];
                v2[0] = u2[0] * mass2 / mass + u1[0] * 2 * dots[a][7] / (mass);
                v2[1] = u2[1];

                // final velocity of two colliding dots is:
                float[] vFinal1 = rotate(v1[0], v1[1], (float) -angleCollision);;
                float[] vFinal2 = rotate(v2[0], v2[1], (float) -angleCollision);;

                if (a != i && !(dots[a][0] == 0 && dots[a][1] == 0)) {
                    // if the x and y distance between the two dots centres is less than their radii combined then the dots have collided
                    boolean thisCollision = Math.pow(xDist, 2) + Math.pow(yDist, 2) <= Math.pow((dots[a][4] + dots[i][4]), 2);

                    //if the dots collided, create new final velocity's from the angle of collision and the x and y velocitys at collision
                    if (thisCollision) {
                        collisionDot = true;
                        dots[i][2] = vFinal1[0];
                        dots[i][3] = vFinal1[1];
                        dots[a][2] = vFinal2[0];
                        dots[a][3] = vFinal2[1];
                        return;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
}

public float[] rotate(float velocityX, float velocityY, float angle) {
    float x1 = (float) (velocityX * Math.cos(angle) - velocityY * Math.sin(angle));
    float y1 = (float) (velocityX * Math.sin(angle) - velocityY * Math.cos(angle));
    float vel[] = new float[2];
    vel[0] = x1;
    vel[1] = y1;
    return vel;
}
```

Comment: Please, please, use classes... And meaningful names. Each time you use `dots[i][x]` I have to look up what that given property is. What are `u1` and `u2`?

Comment: no clue, honestly i was just looking through some algorithms to help. i figured out what the rest are meant to be but not the u1 and u2. all i know is that they are important. the whole thing stops even slightly working without them.